# (Another) question regarding C loops and data structures

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a program (who's code is available at the bottom) which generates a list of numbers the way that I want it to. The program works fine as is and does exactly what I want. I'm just not a fan of the way I wrote it. It returns "Segmentation fault" if I change one thing, which I'll say at the bottom as well. Here's the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define NCH 81

// Generate swap-mode data for bonds for input.conf file

int main() 
{
    int i,j,k;
    int **dat2, *dat;
    //double *dat;

    int ns = 500;

    int nrow = NCH*(ns-1);

    dat = (int*) calloc(nrow, sizeof(int));
    dat2 = (int**) calloc(nrow,sizeof(int*));

    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        dat2[i] = (int*) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
        for (j=0; j<2; j++)
            dat2[i][j] = 0;
    }

    // Generates the bonds
    k=2;
    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        k--;
        for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
            dat2[i][j] = k++;
            if ( ((k%501) == 0) ) { 
                k--;
                dat2[i][j] = k++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *inp2;
    inp2 = fopen("bonds.out", "w");

    for (i=1; i<=nrow; i++)
        fprintf(inp2, "%d %d\n", dat2[i-1][0], dat2[i-1][1]);

    fclose(inp2);

    // Generates the bond ID in the pattern 1 2 3 3 2 1 ... (appropriate for Bond swap!)
    k=1;
    while ( k < nrow ) {
        for (j=0; j<250; j++) {
            dat[k] = (j+1);
            k++;
        }
        for (j=250; j>0; j--) {
            dat[k] = j;
            k++;
        }
    }

    // Scans bonds.out (because just reporting dat2[][] returns segmentation error, not sure why.
    // scans the bonds.out file and stores both values into dm1 and dm2, then reports into 'results.out' file
    int dm1, dm2;

    FILE *inp;
    inp = fopen("input.out", "w");
    inp2 = fopen("bonds.out", "r");

    for (i=1; i<=nrow; i++) {
        fscanf(inp2, "%d %d", &dm1, &dm2);
        fprintf(inp, "%d  %d  %d  %d\n", i, dat[i], dm1, dm2);
    }



    printf("\nDone. All data has been written to \"input.out\"\n");

    fclose(inp2);
    fclose(inp);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I don't like the fact that it's first writing `dat2[][]` to a file and then scanning that file for the values. Why, instead, can't I incorporate `dat2[][]` in the main loop that writes the `"results.out"` file? If I do so, I get Segmentation fault. For clarification, I mean changing these lines in the code:

```
for (i=1; i<=nrow; i++) {
    fscanf(inp2, "%d %d", &dm1, &dm2);
    fprintf(inp, "%d  %d  %d  %d\n", i, dat[i], dm1, dm2);
}
```

To these:

```
for (i=1; i<=nrow; i++) {
    fprintf(inp, "%d  %d  %d  %d\n", i, dat[i], dat2[i-1][0], dat2[i-1][1]);
}
```

I'd love an explanation as I'm still very new to C.

Thanks a lot!
Amit

Comment: That's a lot of code my friend.

Comment: I know. I apologize, really. I don't think you have to read all of it. Perhaps just concentrate on the last bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to subtract 1 from the array index of `dat`, like this:

```
for (i=1; i<=nrow; i++) {
  fscanf(inp2, "%d %d", &dm1, &dm2);
  fprintf(inp, "%d  %d  %d  %d\n", i, dat[i-1], dm1, dm2);
}
```

The reason why this causes a segfault is because you're looping until `i <= nrow`, which will go out of the bounds of `dat` on the final loop iteration.

Comment: +1. On a sidenote @Amit: you do `dat2[i][j] = 0;` which is not really necessary since `calloc()` does that anyway. You also don't check if the files were opened succesfully

Comment: @Muggen: I know calloc initializes, but it doesn't always do a good job. 
@Jacob: dat[] goes from 1 to nrow (inclusive), not from 0 to nrow (exclusive)

Comment: @Amit Really? Um, correct me if I'm wrong here - `dat`'s indices start at 0 and end at `nrow - 1`.

Comment: @Amit Arrays in C are zero-indexed.  Indices of dat range from 0 to nrow-1.

Comment: Ugh...Okay perhaps you guys are right. Yes I am aware of zero-based indexes in C. `dat[]` is not the issue here, it's reporting the right values...when I include `dat2[][]` in there, it fails.

Comment: @Relkin: you're certainly right. Thank you for your input. +1

Comment: @Relkin: I outputted dat[i-1] and it still segfaults. I will now try Muggen's solution

Comment: @Relkin and @Muggen: I think I'll probably code this a lot differently tomorrow as I realize these bugs...Even though both of your solutions didn't fix the segfault (or at least, as far as I could tell), you certainly helped me find two significant bugs in the program.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something else on your code too besides what Relkin (correctly) pointed out.

```
int nrow = NCH*(ns-1);
dat = (int*) calloc(nrow, sizeof(int));
```

If my calculations are right, `nrow == 81*(500-1)` (== 40419) so it is `dat[40419]`

On the following explosive algorithm :

```
k=1;
while ( k < nrow ) {
    for (j=0; j<250; j++) {
        dat[k] = (j+1);
        k++;
    }
    for (j=250; j>0; j--) {
        dat[k] = j;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Every internal `for` loop increases `k` by 250 (so both increase it by 500 for every `while` loop), while `k < 40419`. This means there is a point where `k` reaches 40001, the condition is satisfied and the loop goes one more. At this moment, on the second `for` loop you exceed 40419 and write in memory you shouldn't. Take a look at that and check my maths again plz.

Once you are inside the while loop, and the condition falsifies, this does not mean the loop will automatically exit.

Comment: Ahh you are indeed correct. `dat` is supposed to be 40419, and I think you're certainly right about the `while` loop thing. I wonder why this works ... it should definitely report a segfault. I'll just add an if statement to break the loop. Maybe that'll fix all

Comment: @Amit, this is `Undefined Behaviour`. Anything could happen, either work, either `SegFault` or as some others have said in SO `Get your girlfriend pregnant`

Comment: @Muggen: LOL. I haven't heard that one yet, but thank you for making my fri. night enjoyable and laughable :) +1

Comment: I guess I should mark this answer as the correct one? Both you and Relkin are correct, but I think yours possibly explains the segfault? not sure...what would you do?

Comment: @Amit Why don't you try to integrate both mine and @Muggen's solutions and see which one actually solves the problem?

Comment: Will do, no worries. And I'll definitely correct the answer appropriately. It's just 12AM here and I won't get to it tonight. Do know that if your answer solves my problems, you will most definitely get the check. And given that you are from NY, you should get to bed soon as well! (I'm from PA)

Comment: @Muggen: @#$@#4 still a segfault. Forget it, now is not the time to look at this stuff